# How to access html requests from client with javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, httprequest, href

Hello I am trying to access an Httprequest triggerd by a react component from my javascript code in order to test the url?

can anybody help please ?

[Screenshot of the httprequest I want to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6oGJ.png)

Here is an example of the unit test I'am running, I want to add an other unit test that checks if the httprequest is called correctly.

```
  .add('Search with "Occasion" keyword', () => {
    const result = search('Iphone Occasion');
    specs(() =>
      describe('SEO Navigation Links', () => {
        it('Should not contain "Occasion" keyword', () => {
          const searchValue = result.find(Search).node.state.value.toLowerCase();
          const contains = searchValue.includes('occasion');
          expect(contains).toBeTruthy();
        });
      }),
    );
    return result;
  });
```

Comment: Share some code?

Answer (score 0):

The best i can recommend is to "monkey patch" the fetch function (if it uses that)

```
const realFetch = fetch;
fetch = (...args) => realFetch(...args).then(doStuff);
```

It creates a "middleware", and when the website tries to call the fetch function, it will call yours

Make sure you make a copy of the original function to avoid infinite recursion

Answer (score 0):

If you install a [Service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), you can run some code client-side on all the requests your page makes. I'm not sure what you need to do in order to test the code you are talking about, but a Service Worker could report the request back to your own test code on the page, or respond with whatever content you want, or modify the server's response.

Comment: I'am sorry its for a corporate and I cant install anything for the moment :/

Comment: Service Workers are "installed" by the web page into the browser, and they live in the browser and service requests for the domain that installed them. It's not the same as installing software, or even installing a browser extension. Web pages are allowed to "install" them without any user interaction. It's more like setting a cookie or using local storage, or starting a background web worker.